# trying to query the house details of the house having highest occupancy. If i am using max in sql server with inner join, its giving me error

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get data that is the maximum value in a table where the column on which `max` is used is derived mathematically. It's not showing any syntax error but on running giving me:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 350
>   Column 'dbo.Addresses.house_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
select DBO.Addresses.house_id, dbo.Addresses.name , dbo.Houses.house_type, DBO.Houses.bhk_details, DBO.Houses.furnishing_type,dbo.Houses.bed_count,DBO.Houses.Beds_vacant, max (dbo.Houses.bed_count - DBO.Houses.Beds_vacant) AS TOTAT_OCC 
from dbo.Addresses
     INNER JOIN DBO.Houses ON 
         dbo.Addresses.house_id= dbo.Houses.house_id
```

If I don't use `max` I am getting the right result

```
select  DBO.Addresses.house_id, dbo.Addresses.name , dbo.Houses.house_type, DBO.Houses.bhk_details, DBO.Houses.furnishing_type, (dbo.Houses.bed_count - DBO.Houses.Beds_vacant) AS TOTAT_OCC 
from dbo.Addresses
     INNER JOIN DBO.Houses ON 
         dbo.Addresses.house_id= dbo.Houses.house_id 
ORDER BY TOTAT_OCC DESC
```

How will i get rows having maximum values of total_occ

Comment: The error is clear. You need to group by all columns that aren't in the aggregate, or use max() over...

Comment: You cannot use aggregate functions without grouping the data - the error is telling you what you would need to do. If you do not want to group by all columns, create a temp table/derived table/CTE with the MAX value you want, grouped how you want and then join it over to the main query.

Comment: Could you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this sample? It would help us help you.

Comment: `1 Zaanz appartment Apartment 3 BHK unfurnished 3
7 UDB Building Apartment 3 BHK semifurnished 3
8 Apoorva society Apartment 2 BHK fully-furnished 3
14 Nestaway building Apartment 3 BHK fully-furnished 3
16 Indira society Apartment 3 BHK fully-furnished 3
4 orchids building Apartment 2 BHK fully-furnished 2` i need rows where 3 is present at last column

Answer (score 0):

Use `top (1) with ties...order by TOTAT_OCC desc` to get the rows corresponding to the max `TOTAT_OCC`:

```
select top (1) with ties DBO.Addresses.house_id, dbo.Addresses.name , dbo.Houses.house_type, DBO.Houses.bhk_details, DBO.Houses.furnishing_type, (dbo.Houses.bed_count - DBO.Houses.Beds_vacant) AS TOTAT_OCC 
from dbo.Addresses
     INNER JOIN DBO.Houses ON 
         dbo.Addresses.house_id= dbo.Houses.house_id 
ORDER BY TOTAT_OCC DESC
```